# undefined method `to_key' for -- NOT USING MONGO

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I found a gazillion answers for my issue if I was using Mongo, but none of the ones I see work out here since I am not using mongo.

Basically I have a report_controller.rb that has a very simple method defined:

```
def donations_by_season
  @donations = Donation    
end
```

and a very simple report/donations_by_season.html.erb as follows:

```
<%= form_for @donations do |f| %>
  Stuff Will go here... such as fields to select a date for the season we wish to view.
<% end %>
```

There is no report model, just a controller and views.

But when I attempt to view /reports/donations_by_season
I immediately get:

> undefined method `to_key' for #<Class:0x00000114d85918>`

What should I do to fix that? Am I doing my form incorrectly since there is no model associated with reports?

Comment: Should I create a report model even though there is no corresponding table in the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should never be assigning an instance variable to point to a class object like this. You probably want this:

```
def donations_by_season
  @donations = Donation.all
end
```

Note the `.all` versus just leaving it blank. You could also do `.new` or a litany of other methods, depending on what you're trying to do.

Comment: Good catch. I agree I do not want it blank.  changing it to all makes the query run too long though since I have hundreds of thousands of records in there.  But it does remind me how great it would be to use a scope there once the season parameter exists.  something like Donation.season(:param[:season]) or something I imagine.

Comment: `Donation.where(:season => params[:season])` would get you part of the way there, and a `.limit(100)` would solve your "too many records" problem.

Comment: Having nothing after Donation was causing the original error message, thanks!